# redirect to another link if the first link returns "404 Not Found"

Tags: nginx

How can i redirect to another link if the first link returns "404 Not Found"?

what i've tried

```
    location ^~ /video/ {
                    rewrite ^/video/(\w+)/(.+)$ /get.php?hash=$1&filename=$2 last;
                    rewrite ^/video/(\w+)/(.+)$ http://domain.com/get.php?hash=$1&filename=$2 last;
                    root /storage/;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `error_page` directive to your nginx `location` block:

See [nginx documentation reference](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page).

```
location ^~ /video/ {
    error_page   404          /video/404.php;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) might do what you need:

```
try_files first_link second_link third_link etc
```

Basically it sends the user to the first link that is available.

Comment: @teslasimus - the 2nd example (mongrel) in the docs goes to a link. Does that not work in your case?

Comment: nope, i'm getting nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is not allowed here